# Wordpress: Display all posts in a custom taxonomy's category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got a Wordpress post query that is supposed to retrieve all posts from the following:

1. A custom post type called '**links**'
2. Belongs to a category "**links_category1**", which is part of a custom taxonomy called "links_categories"
3. Every post that fits the above two conditions should be retrieved, regardless of whether it's also assigned to a subcategory of "**links_category1**" or not.

The query below manages to meet the first two criteria. But it fails at the third. For some reason, it only retrieves posts that are assigned to the category "**links_category1**" AND a subcategory of that category (i.e: category "**links_category1_A**"). For example, it retrieves a post that is assigned to categories "**links_category1**" and "**links_category1_A**". But it doesn't retrieve posts that are assigned to only "**links_category1**".

```
// The category is retrieved by its ID number
$taxonomy_category = 'links_category1;

$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'links',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'links_categories',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $taxonomy_category,
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

// Set up the post query
$the_query_links_list = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I was wondering whether anyone can shed light on what I may be missing.

Thanks,

Comment: `// The category is retrieved by its ID number` - is it, actually? The (faulty) code you have shown looks more like you provided the category slug.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for replying. It turns out, the code was doing its job. I just found that my problem was caused because the parent theme's settings wasn't allowing what I wanted.